# Discovered - currently not indexed VS Crawled - currently not indexed

Tags: google-search-console

In Google search console I have a 883 webpages `Discovered - currently not indexed` and only 4 webpages `Crawled - currently not indexed`.

But, from a `site:example.com` it appears that 45 webpages are crawled (and ranked).

So, **883, 4 or 45**, what to understand from this?

Comment: How old is the site.  It can can several weeks for your pages to be indexed.  Furthermore, Google makes no promises to index a page once it's crawled.

Comment: @Trebor the site existed for about 5 months but I changed a domain so technically 1 month (with the new domain) without domain migration ; I understand that for you crawled as "discovered".